# Are single-entity datastore writes atomic?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the AppEngine DataStore, given an entity `a = MyModel(a=1, b=2)`, is `a.put()` atomic? That is, if I run:

```
a.a=3
a.b=4
a.put()
```

Am I guaranteed that the entity was updated correctly for all its properties, (assuming `a.put()` did not raise an exception, that is)?

Dan Sanderson's [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596522735.do) says that [it is](https://books.google.pl/books?id=6cL_kCZ4NJ4C&lpg=PA165&ots=sJhjMRTYjn&dq=%22When%20you%20create%2C%20update%20or%20delete%20a%20single%20entity%2C%20the%20change%20occurs%20in%20a%20transaction%22&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q=%22When%20you%20create,%20update%20or%20delete%20a%20single%20entity,%20the%20change%20occurs%20in%20a%20transaction%22&f=true), but I couldn't find concrete documentation on the subject elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a single entity's update is atomic.

As noted [in this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write), a given entity is a single protocol buffer in a Bigtable row. Protocol buffers are always written atomically.

Comment: Could you please point me to some documentation that says so?

Comment: I think I've found something that states it conclusively. My initial reply was based simply on my knowledge as someone who works at Google and thus knows the systems behind the Datastore.

Comment: does everyone agree on the definition of atomic data, are you saying the data exists as a discrete record?

Comment: @peterretief Are you familiar with protocol buffers?

Comment: @Amber not until about 5 seconds ago, interesting

Answer (score -2):

**Yes & no.**

It's atomic but it is **eventually consistent**. It can make a huge difference to business logic if not taken into account properly.

E.g. if you did:

```
a = A(id=1)
a.b = 2
a.c = 3
a.put()
.... wait some time
a = A(id=1)
a.b = 4
a.c = 5
a.put()
....
# check now
```

and if you query a = db.get_by_key(1) it will always have a.b==2 and a.c==3.

But if you query the entity by index it can give different results.

For example if you query at the same time

```
A.query(A.b==4)
A.query(A.c==5)
```

then one (any) of the queries can return you 1 record and other return nothing. Or both return 1 record. Or both return nothing *for some period of time*. Eventually it will always return stable 1 record for each query. But **timing is no guaranteed** - usually it takes milliseconds but can be few seconds or even minutes or hours in case of big issues.

You may be interested to read more about this:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/

Comment: This is a complete non-sequitur. The question asks nothing about consistency, or even reading back the data at all.

Comment: I understand what you mean and strictly speaking yes, you are right.

I just believe there is not enough context to know it for sure what exactly was asked as the fact it should be atomic is pretty obvious from the fact that there is just a single .put() call. It's not like you update 1 property,then another without any put (suppose it's called automatically somehow the same way as ndb does autobatching for get().) and ask if this would be atomic.

Theoretically it's possible that a person have issue with consistency.